# Why is this apache php piped log script not working properly?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, logging, pipe

i have a piped logging program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while(true) {
  $l = fread($fd,8192);
  $l = trim($l);
  if($l =="") continue;
  file_put_contents('/home/proxy/testfile',$l."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
fclose($fd);
```

and in my webserver config i have:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" proxylog
CustomLog "|/home/proxy/logger.php" proxylog
```

the weird thing is that i do recieve some log input that is written, but only very rarely. far less than in the default log file. i also cant recognise a pattern.

i also waited long enough and successfully checked for missing log lines from a time frame before the last log entry in my custom piped log - to eliminiate the possibility that a buffer caused this. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script doesn't exactly match what is expected for an Apache piped log script so what exactly is output is likely undefined. A minimal PHP example is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

<?php
$stdin = fopen ('php://stdin', 'r');
ob_implicit_flush (true); // Use unbuffered output
while ($line = fgets ($stdin))
{
    print $line;
}
?>
```

See http://www.sudleyplace.com/pipederrorlogs.html for more details. First get it working so it simply outputs everything it receives and then add features to it as needed.

Comment: i was not a ware that you need to print the input. didnt see that in the official documentation either. but doesnt seem to help. i thought my example was quite minimal, took yours and added the line to write to another file so i can see whether it works. tested from hand in the shell works fine. is my log format defnition fine?

Comment: The `print` was used in this case as he was forwarding the pipe to another file via `ErrorLog "|/path/to/script/script >>/path/to/logfile/logfile"`. Sending the output to another file like in your case would be fine as well. Your LogFormat looks fine as well. You can test the LogFormat by just outputting to a normal log file and making sure what you want is being output. You can also replace the PHP script with a simple shell script for testing to make sure the piped log is actually working.

Comment: i think i messed something up with the places where i defined the logs... thanks for the hint with the unbuffered output and clearifying the stdout issue. now i am a bit more clever tough i am going with another solution i am following the file using tail which is just fine.